# Database connection variable not being found only on one page

Tags: php, mysqli

The connection file is:

```
$DBconnect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "project" );
```

And this works on all pages except one, which is giving this error:
Undefined variable: DBconnect

for this part:

```
include_once('connection.php');
// Function that will convert a user id into their username
function getusername($uid) {

$res = mysqli_query($DBconnect, "SELECT username FROM users WHERE id='".$uid."' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
```

Thanks for advice

Comment: You define the variable in the global scope, but try to access it in function scope. That does not work. Try this inside the function: `$_GLOBALS['DBconnect']`

Comment: Read up about variable scope. But for a quick fix, include the line `global $DBconnect;` in the function.

Comment: 1. Make sure that this is the correct path to connection.php.
2. It is defined in your global and not the needed(function) scope.

Comment: Ah yes thanks trying to use the global variable in the function was the problem

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
    function getusername($uid){
$res = mysqli_query($DBconnect, "SELECT username FROM users WHERE id='".$uid."' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

to this

```
    function getusername($uid){
    global $DBconnect;
    $res = mysqli_query($DBconnect, "SELECT username FROM users WHERE id='".$uid."' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
    }
```

or

```
function getusername($uid,$DBconnect){
        $res = mysqli_query($DBconnect, "SELECT username FROM users WHERE id='".$uid."' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a scope issue.

`$DBConnect` is available in the Global scope, but you cannot get access to the global scope in a function automatically. So pass the `$DBConnect` as a parameter to the function and all is well.

```
include_once('connection.php');

function getusername($uid, $DBConnect) {

    $res = mysqli_query($DBconnect, "SELECT username 
                                     FROM users 
                                     WHERE id='$uid' LIMIT 1"); 
    if ( ! $res ) {
       echo mysql_error();
       exit;
    }

}

// call function with an extra parameter i.e. the $DBConnect

getusername($uid, $DBConnect);
```